# How to write Java String.format to ruby code?

Tags: java, ruby

How to write this code in ruby? I can't understand  **String.format("%04d", validateHash(hash) ? ((0xFC
& hash[0]) << 5) | (hash[hash.length - 1] & 0x7F) : 0);**

```
private static final int MINIMUM_HASH_LENGTH = 20;

public static String calculateVerificationCode(byte[] hash) {
    return String.format("%04d", validateHash(hash) ? ((0xFC & hash[0]) << 5) | (hash[hash.length - 1] & 0x7F) : 0);
}

private static boolean validateHash(byte[] hash) {
    return hash != null && hash.length >= MINIMUM_HASH_LENGTH;
}
```

Comment: What part don't you understand?  The formatting or the expression that gives the number to format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's go step by step over the bit operations

Let's imagine our hash is `"some_string"` and the byte representation is:

```rb
input = "some_string"
hash = input.bytes
# -> [115, 111, 109, 101, 95, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]
```

The first part is to take the first byte of your array `115` and do a bitwise AND operation with `252` (`FC` is the hex representation of `252`). If we convert these to binary it would look like this:

```
(0xFC & hash[0]):
0011111100
0001110011
---------------
0001110000
```

The result will get shifted to the left by 5

```
0001110000 -> 000111000000000
```

The next step is to take the last element of your array and do a bitwise AND (&) operation with `127` (`7F` is the hex representation of `127`).

```
(hash[hash.length - 1] & 0x7F):
0001100111
0001111111
---------------
0001100111
```

The last step is now to take both of these results and do a bitwise OR operation

```
((0xFC & hash[0]) << 5) | (hash[hash.length - 1] & 0x7F)
000111000000000
000000001100111
---------------
000111001100111
```

If we convert this to an integer we will get `3687`.

The magic numbers 127 and 252 are probably carefully chosen to guarantee a good distribution so take them as given. We would need to get more information where this is taken from to explain these values.

The validation also makes sure that the hash has at least 20 bytes otherwise these operations probably don't produce a good distribution.

The whole Ruby codes would look like this:

```rb
def calculateVerificationCode(hash)
  return 0 unless hash&.length >= 20

  (((0xFC & hash[0]) << 5) | (hash[hash.length - 1] & 0x7F)).to_s.rjust(4, "0")
end

puts calculateVerificationCode("a really long string foobar".bytes)
```

The `to_s.rjust(4, "0")` makes sure to pad with zeros on the left if the number is smaller than 1000.

Comment: Interesting. Haven't seen a "real" application of bitwise shift in Ruby — or Java, for that matter — before.

Comment: @BobRodes - It's used in Estonian Online authentication method for calculating security code which is displayed to user.